# How can I run a linux build on an NTFS drive?

Tags: sudo, executable

I'm running under Ubuntu but using a shared drive which is NTFS formatted. I've got blender sitting in a folder (it's the 2.66RC build with some trivial python customisations.) I'm calling blender from a script, which is why I want a contained, local copy of the program that won't get updated.

The whole thing runs cheerfully on my desktop but the minute I move it to the shared drive, I run into problems. First I have to skip all the symlinks because NTFS doesn't support them (I have to skip libGL.so and libGLU.so, along with their respective *.so.1 selves.)

Then I can't run the `blender` binary directly because you can't change NTFS file permissions with `chmod`. So I have to run it using `sudo bash blender-2.66RC/blender`, at which point I get the message,

> cannot execute binary file

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? It would mean a lot less organisational hassle if I could work off the shared drive rather than keep copying everything over to my desktop and back.

Comment: You can't run a binary with Bash. Try running it with [`ld.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a sparse file/disk on the NTFS share, format the sparse disk as ext3 or whatever works happily with your Blender app.

Sparse file/disk management manual from Arch Linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sparse_file

Answer (score 0):

`sudo bash blender-2.66RC/blender` only makes sense if `blender-2.66RC/blender` is a bash script. Is it? Run `file blender-2.66RC/blender` (or `sudo file blender-2.66RC/blender` if necessary) to check.

If the problem is that you have the permission to read the `blender` file but not execute it, then `sudo` won't help. What you need is to call the loader for the `blender` program and pass it the `blender` file as an argument. If `blender` is a script, the loader is the interpreter, e.g. `bash blender-2.66RC/blender` if it's a bash script, `python blender-2.66RC/blender` if it's a Python script, etc. If `blender` is a binary, then the loader is the dynamic loader: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 blender-2.66RC/blender` for a 32-bit x86 binary, or `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 blender-2.66RC/blender` for a 64-bit x86 binary.

If `blender` is executable but you don't have the permission to access it, then a plain `sudo blender-2.66RC/blender` is what you need. If `blender` is neither executable nor readable, combine the two workarounds, e.g. `sudo /lib/ld-linux.so.2 blender-2.66RC/blender`.

---

This is a rather strange situation. Hard disk space is cheap. Instead of fiddling with a removable drive (slow, unreliable), copy the files to your hard disk. You'll be able to set the permissions correctly, and you'll waste a lot less time fiddling with a removable drive, and you won't lose files when you drop the disk.